# Какими словами обозначается печатное и рукописное начертания?

Tags: грамотная-речь, оформление-текста, курсив

Какие существуют виды начертания текста от руки?
Письменный (рукописный) и печатный текст? Слово "курсив" применимо только к машинному (компьютерному) набору?

Answer (score 1):

В настоящее время рукописное письмо представлено следующими формами:

**скоропись** — скорописное письмо, используемое в быту, в частной переписке, характеризующееся упрощённостью, отсутствием декоративности и лишних штрихов, экономностью в движениях и темпом;
**стенография** — письмо посредством особых знаков и целого ряда сокращений, позволяющее быстро записывать устную речь;
**каллиграфия** (от греч. *καλλιγραφία* — «красивый почерк») — искусство красивого и четкого письма, в котором особенно ярко проявляются особенности шрифтовой графики, выразительность, экспрессивность, гармоничность и художественная образность шрифтовых форм.
(По материалам книги П. Кашевского [Шрифтовая графика](https://books.google.ee/books?id=6kptDwAAQBAJ&pg=PP6&lpg=PP6&dq=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=qV8AnWt95L&sig=ACfU3U1pLAtlweCZbwhqMs5GJsSKHLFjlg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiy0ZXG_eXgAhXSqIsKHanrBAQ4ChDoATAEegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE&f=false).)

[***курсив***](https://slovar.cc/rus/ojegov/595952.html)

В словаре Ожегова:
наклонный (вправо) **типографский шрифт**, подобный рукописному почерку.
Выделить цитату курсивом.

В словаре терминов изобразительного искусства:
шрифт с округленными и наклонными буквами, **имитирующий текст, написанный от руки.**

В большой советской энциклопедии:
(нем. *Kursiv*, от позднелат. *cursivus*, буквально — бегущий)
1) одно из начертаний рисунка **типографского шрифта** , характеризующееся наклоном вправо, близким к рукописному; предназначается для выделения частей набора.

Вывод: *курсив* — это особенность шрифта, относящаяся только к печатному (типографскому, компьютерному, машинному) тексту.

Answer (score 0):

Пишут либо просто *"от руки"* (начинающих учат только письму с наклоном), либо *"печатными **буквами**"*. *"Курсив"* относится только к типографскому или машинному тексту, это *наклонная* разновиднисть ***шрифта***, имитирующая наклонный характер типичного рукописного текста.